# Strange characters present in gcc compilation output message on console

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-10.04

When I build a C code using gcc, Makefile as below on a Ubuntu 10.04-x32 bit system, under bash shell. The gcc output message has some unwanted characters in the output message(see below: â).

```
test@dualboot-desktop:~/test/opencv$ make
cc -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_video -lopencv_calib3d test1.c -o test_opencv
test1.c: In function âmainâ:
test1.c:13: error: too few arguments to function âcvLoadImageâ
test1.c:21: error: expected â;â before âcvMoveWindowâ
make: *** [test_opencv] Error 1
```

They jumble up the actual message sometimes and get pesky.

What is the cause of that? Anything wrong in my user settings on ubunti

How can I fix that?

Comment: Those `â` things seem to represent quotation marks. A character encoding problem, maybe?

Comment: Either a bad locale or a bad console font. What does the `locale` command say? Can you see quote symbols in`man ascii`?

Comment: my locale seems to set to:- LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: This happens to me if I use Linux console or xterm with any UTF-8 locale. It doesn't happen with konsole (the KDE terminal emulator), and it doesn't happen with C and POSIX locales. Choose your poison.

Comment: @n.m - So how do I set my locale to C or POSIX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set LC_LANG to something that ends in UTF8 but your terminal is having problems (or is not configured to handle) UTF8, then you run into trouble.

Either configure your terminal or set LC_LANG=en_GB.

Comment: Thanks If say export LANG=en_GB then the problem did get solve. But this change would be lost when I close this terminal and next time start a new one. How to change locale/LANG on global basis?

Comment: put `export LANG=en_GB` into your .bashrc file.

Comment: had the same problem in my Clion console. Changing the console encoding fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with application "Terminal" under linux mint.

Solution:
Terminal (4th menu tab), zurücksetzen/reset, (2nd menu choice from below).
The annoying symbol was a single quote '.

To make it permanent, choose Einstellungen/Settings (2nd menu tab, last choice), then advanced, then Zeichensatz/Character set, change it to "UTF-8" (was some strange ISO, not even 8859-1, in my case)