# Ubuntu server outputs messages in funky characters

Tags: ubuntu, locale, output

I just installed Ubuntu server 13.10.  I just started using and when I compile code in `C` I get funky output:

```
warning: format â%sâ expects argument of type âchar *â, but argument 2 has type âMYSQL_ROWâ [-Wformat=]
     printf("number of free = %s\n", row);
```

I didn't change any settings and did default install.  Does anyone know how to fix this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange characters present in gcc compilation output message on console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537520/strange-characters-present-in-gcc-compilation-output-message-on-console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your locale and/or terminal character set is configured for some legacy 8-bit encoding. At a minimum, make sure they agree; in the worst case, force everything to 7-bit ASCII; but in this day and age, Unicode should be the baseline.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee can you guide me on how to configure locale settings?

Comment: I tried this to no avail:  Add `en_US.ISO-8859-1 ISO-8859-1` to `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` and then type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locale`.  I looked at the other posts with no success, and  particular suggestions?

Comment: ISO-8859-1 is probably wrong for a modern terminal, try with UTF-8 instead, and/or a different terminal (good ole `xterm` maybe!)

Comment: Thanks.  Actually I was using SSH to connect to the server.  So I see that I was using ISO8859-1 on my local machine and my server was using UTF-8.   So there were misaligned.  When I switched my local to utf8 it worked.